# Наложение фрагментов

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Столкнулся с проблемой: при нажатии на день календаря должен вызываться новый фрагмент, в котором нужно добавить событие. После добавления и нажатия submit мы возвращаемся на фрагмент с календарем. Так вот: обратный вызов проходит без проблем, а при клике на дату фрагмент событий появляется поверх фрагмента календаря.

**Вот класс с календарём:**

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    FrameLayout calendarFL;
    CalendarView calendar;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
                             final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
        calendarFL = (FrameLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.calendarFL);
        calendar = (CalendarView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                            int dayOfMonth) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment = new EventsFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.eventFL,fragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
        return v;    
    }
}
```

**Ниже класс фрагмента событий** (пока реализую только переход между фрагментами):

```
public class EventsFragment extends Fragment {

    Button submit;
    FrameLayout eventFL;
    TextInputLayout eventDetails;
    EditText eventDet;
    CheckBox addAlarm;
    Spinner events;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events,container,false);
        eventFL = (FrameLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.eventFL);
        submit = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        eventDetails = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.eventdetTIL);
        eventDet = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.eventdetailET);
        addAlarm = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.alarmCKB);
        events = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.eventSpinner);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment = new MainActivityFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.calendarFL,fragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

**Макет календаря:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/calendarFL">

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Макет событий:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/eventFL">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/topRL">

            <CheckBox
                android:text="@string/add_alarm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/alarmCKB"
                android:checked="false"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/eventSpinner"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bottomRL"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topRL">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/eventdetTIL">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:hint="@string/type_details_of_event"
                    android:id="@+id/eventdetailET"
                    android:layout_height="300dp" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:text="@string/submit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/submitButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/eventdetTIL"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Если я в `MainActivityFragment` пишу `ft.replace(R.id.eventFL,fragment);` то приложение вылетает без каких-либо логов.

Если пишу `ft.replace(R.id.calendarFL,fragment);` происходит наложение.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Вот такая ошибка отловилась в логах. Не пойму, как не находится view...

> E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0d0083 (com.carrickane.miftestapp:id/eventFL) for fragment EventsFragment{1752ec5 #2 id=0x7f0d0083}

Может, ответ элементарно прост, но пока не осилил.

Answer (score 1):

В методе `replace` первым аргументом идёт ИД контейнера для фрагментов. Вы же пытаетесь поместить один фрагмент в другой. Это ID должен быть одинаков и должен указывать на элемент разметки, содержащей ваши фрагменты

Comment: Спасибо, я понял ошибку. Использовал FrameLayout в каждом макете...